# Arduino Xbee Shield - Date Translation

Tags: arduino, byte, xbee

I've got two Arduino/Xbees set up over a network and trying to send an analog voltage reading from one to the other. I'm sending the raw integer analog reading across (1-1028 reading) to be translated into a voltage on the second Arduino unit.

So question is - how do I unpack two bytes? I'm using byteHigh and byteLow commands to read the serial value and assembling these two with a Word function, but this isn't working properly. The Word turns out something completely unrelated to the actual analog V sent.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `byteHigh<<8+byteLow` doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're using?